# How to send the value of JavaScript to PHP and then My SQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to save the image or the value of the QR code/decodedText variable into My SQL database using PHP. Here is the code:

```
 <div class="container" style="padding-left: 25%;"> 
  <div class="row"> 
   <div id="qr-reader" style="width: 600px"></div> 
  </div> 
 </div>
```

And the JavaScript

```
    <script> 
     function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) { 
     console.log(`Code scanned = ${decodedText}`, decodedResult); 
     } 
   var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner( "qr-reader", { 
     fps: 10, qrbox: 250 }); 
     html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess); 
    </script>
```

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/html5-qrcode@2.0.9/dist/html5-qrcode.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fetch and formData

```
fetch("file.php", method:"POST", data: formData)
```

then in php you connect with mysql

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$conn->query("ISERT INTO .....")
```